# Firmata: how to set a particular pin to high on boot?

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, c, firmata, johnny-five

I'm working on a project that use [J5](http://johnny-five.io/), so is using the standard firmata, this project is using an opto 4 channel relay, when the board is booting the pins state are set to low, so as soon as I power the board my relay goes to a close state and make my motor run... this is a wrong behaviour for my purpose. How can I avoid that? By googleing around I stumble acros this:

[A possible solution](https://github.com/firmata/arduino/blob/master/examples/StandardFirmata/StandardFirmata.ino#L290-L295)

but I can't uderstand if this is what I'm looking for.. plus I need only the PIN 7 to be set high on boot, any help please?

**EDIT: SCHEMATICS**

[4 Channel 5V Relay Module](http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/index.php?title=4_Channel_5V_Relay_Module)

[image]

Comment: What makes you believe it boots with all pins LOW? They should be high impedance. Could you share the schematic of how you connect the Arduino to the optocoupler, to the the relays and to the motors?

Comment: @EdgarBonet added schematics in the question ;)

Comment: This is not a schematic. And it only shows how you are powering your relay module, not how you are driving it, nor how it works internally (reference please).

Comment: @EdgarBonet added the references link to the constructor wiki page

Comment: @EdgarBonet I forgot in the schema above to connect the pin 7 to the ch1, sorry

Comment: Why you don't put an inverter between pin 7 and the relay?

Answer (score 3):

It would seem you are right. If I understood the source correctly,
Firmata initializes all digital pins as OUTPUT LOW. Hard to believe, as
this seems like a silly thing to do... My understanding is that:

1. `setup()` calls `systemResetCallback()` in order to set the initial
   pin configuration ([line 779](https://github.com/firmata/arduino/blob/master/examples/StandardFirmata/StandardFirmata.ino#L779))
2. `systemResetCallback()` loops over all pins and calls
   `setPinModeCallback(i, OUTPUT)` for every pin `i` that is not an
   analog pin ([line 732](https://github.com/firmata/arduino/blob/master/examples/StandardFirmata/StandardFirmata.ino#L732))
3. `setPinModeCallback()` calls `pinMode()` to set the pin to OUTPUT
   ([line 325](https://github.com/firmata/arduino/blob/master/examples/StandardFirmata/StandardFirmata.ino#L325)).

If my understanding is correct, then the simplest solution would seem to
patch `systemResetCallback()` and replace `OUTPUT` by `INPUT` on
line 732.

Comment: yep, my same conclusion but I think that setting all the pins to INPUT will cause the same but opposite problem for other components.. best would be set the desired pin number

Comment: Irrespective of how you patch Firmata, the pins will be set to INPUT when you power the Arduino, and during the time the bootloader runs. You should manage for you circuit to accommodate that initial state. A pullup or pulldown resistor may be suitable for the pins driving those other components.

Comment: how does it take to boot less than a second would be acceptable

Answer (score 1):

Just put `digitalWrite(anyPin,HIGH)` in `void setup()` this will make that specific pin `HIGH` to reset. It works for me.

```
void setup()
{
  digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
  Firmata.setFirmwareVersion(FIRMATA_FIRMWARE_MAJOR_VERSION, FIRMATA_FIRMWARE_MINOR_VERSION);

  Firmata.attach(ANALOG_MESSAGE, analogWriteCallback);
  Firmata.attach(DIGITAL_MESSAGE, digitalWriteCallback);
  Firmata.attach(REPORT_ANALOG, reportAnalogCallback);
  Firmata.attach(REPORT_DIGITAL, reportDigitalCallback);
  Firmata.attach(SET_PIN_MODE, setPinModeCallback);
  Firmata.attach(SET_DIGITAL_PIN_VALUE, setPinValueCallback);
  Firmata.attach(START_SYSEX, sysexCallback);
  Firmata.attach(SYSTEM_RESET, systemResetCallback);

  // to use a port other than Serial, such as Serial1 on an Arduino Leonardo or Mega,
  // Call begin(baud) on the alternate serial port and pass it to Firmata to begin like this:
  // Serial1.begin(57600);
  // Firmata.begin(Serial1);
  // However do not do this if you are using SERIAL_MESSAGE

  Firmata.begin(57600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for ATmega32u4-based boards and Arduino 101
  }

  systemResetCallback();  // reset to default config
}
```